# WP создает странные дубли картинок

Tags: wordpress

В последнее время с нашим сайтом на WP происходит странная штука. Картинки сами по себе дублируются. И причем не с оригинальными названиями а с числовыми, например 5-3-4-1-1-1.jpg. Плагинов работающего с фотками не стоит. Что это может быть и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Это значит что ты загружаешь одинаковые имена файлов.

Comment: @SeVlad Так в том то и прикол. Я выяснил что для каждого нового группового поля создается новая картинка. 
Это происходит автоматически. У меня на сервере 1 и таже фотка дублируется раз 20.  И так для каждого поста.

Comment: Какой "прикол"? Одинаковых имён файлов не может быть в принципе.

Comment: @SeVlad Они дублятся под разными именами. Например первая картинка 1-1, вторая 1-1-1, третья 1-1-1-1.

Comment: Всё верно, так и должно быть. К существующим именам и слагам прибавляется суффикс `-1` .